# Connecting a parallel LCD using ST7789 with STM32H743VI

Tags: stm32, lcd, parallel

I have a STM32H743VI that I want to connect to a LCD display that uses ST7789 with parallel interface (8 or 16 bit), the LCD doesn't have the SPI signals so I have to use the parallel interface.

I am wondering on how to use the DMA controller in order to speed up the copies between internal buffers and the screen buffer.

I am planning on implementing a simple driver for LittlevGL.

My questions are:

1. Which GPIO ports can be used with the DMA controller of the STM32H743VI?
2. Do I have to use the TIM1/8 timer in order to push the data from the buffer to the GPIO?
3. Is it worth while to use the Chrom-ART accelerator? how hard is it to use it?

Comment: Would you mind telling 1) what the exact display module type is, 2) preferably link to a datasheet, and 3) do you mean the parallel MCU interface or parallel RGB interface?

Comment: 1. NHD-2.4-240320CF-CSXN#-F http://www.newhavendisplay.com/specs/NHD-2.4-240320CF-CSXN-F.pdf 2. MCU parallel, the driver is st7789

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The STM32H732VI has a LCD-TFT peripheral to drive the RGB interface directly, but if you don't want to use it, you better use the Flexible Memory Controller (FMC) peripheral to map the LCD display into memory bus, so DMA can be used with it. Connecting it to simple GPIOs can't really use DMA, or at least it would be awkward to use DMA to toggle GPIOs to get memory reads/writes to the LCD.

1) The FMC pins must be used - just any GPIOs will not do.

2) The DMA controller can do memory-to-memory DMA block transfers. I don't see how the timer would be used for DMA transfers in this case.

3) Maybe Chrom-Art is worth using, if you need operations that it can perform, but the usefullness to directly use it over FMC to drive external framebuffer can be limited. At least you can use it on internal framebuffer that you can then copy to your display, if the Chrom-Art output is not directly compatible.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!. I tried to find which pins in this MCU are the FMC and couldn't find it. What should I look for in the datasheet? Also I am using the 743 and not 732

Comment: The pins are listed in the datasheet alternate pin function list. The bus modes and their operation are explained in the reference manual. Maybe just use CubeMX tool to get started.